# Error with TFS while trying to connect with workspace

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Hello I am trying to bind my work space and I have been doing that with edit work space option and when I bind it for the first time, it had been giving message that if I want to download all the files from the server but I do not see that option from my home computer.

How can I download the latest files from the server, once I have bound my workspace with the server?

Comment: Using TFSExplorer you get the latest source code... Once you create a workspace, TFS keeps track of it with the UserId. Now that you already have a workspace somewhere else you go to manage workspaces and create a new one at your home computer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up the Source Control Explorer (from Team Explorer).  Select your workspace from the workspace drop-down in the toolbar.  Right click the project in Source Control Explorer and choose Get Latest Version, or Get Specific Version.